# How to add JSON request and response examples in Swagger (OpenApi)?

Tags: symfony, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, nelmioapidocbundle

I have an API endpoint in my Symfony 4 application, that I want to document with NelmioApiDocBundle and Swagger. The endpoint takes JSON as a request data and also returns some custom JSON as the response. How can I add examples of them to the documentation, using annotations? I can't see any of the examples on the documentation page, only the description.

```
/**
 * @Route("/order/import", methods={"POST"}, name="order_import")
 * @OA\RequestBody (
 *     request="order",
 *     description="Order data in JSON format",
 *     @OA\Schema(
 *        type="object",
 *        example={"hello": "world"}
 *     )
 * )
 * @OA\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="Returns the JSON data after import",
 *     @OA\Schema(
 *        type="object",
 *        example={"foo": "bar"}
 *     )
 * )
 * @OA\Tag(name="import")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For NelmioApiDocBundle v4 you can do like this

```
use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

/**
 * @OA\Parameter(
 *     name="body",
 *     in="path",
 *     required=true,
 *     @OA\JsonContent(
 *        type="object",
 *        @OA\Property(property="property1", type="number"),
 *        @OA\Property(property="property2", type="number"),
 *     ),
 * )
 *
 * @OA\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="",
 *     @OA\JsonContent(
 *        type="object",
 *        @OA\Property(property="property1", type="number"),
 *        @OA\Property(property="property2", type="number"),
 *     )
 * )
 */
```

For v3

```
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;

/**
 * @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="body",
 *     in="body",
 *     required=true,
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *         @SWG\Property(property="test1", type="string"),
 *         @SWG\Property(property="test2", type="string"),
 *     ),
 * )
 *
 * @SWG\Response(
 *     description="",
 *     response=200,
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *         @SWG\Property(property="test1", type="string"),
 *         @SWG\Property(property="test2", type="string"),
 *     ),
 * )
 */
```

But better to do it via @Model annotation, as described in the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html#use-models) if you have DTO or entity.

Comment: thanks, using `@OA\JsonContent` did the trick! But instead of `@OA\Parameter` I used `@OA\RequestBody` to better represent the request in the `api/doc`